# Send email with Node.js application in Openshift hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, openshift

I have my Node.js application hosting in Openshift to test it and I want to send email. I have a contact form and I would like to receive the message by mail. In local I setup nodemailer with my Gmail account but when I try it in Openshift it does't work because of the security conditions of Google...

I don't have any idea to solve this so if someone had a trick !

Thank's

Comment: you'll need to create an application password for your account at Google, and then use that password in your application.

Comment: There's special instructions for setting up gmail on nodemailer [github page](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) > To use Gmail you may need to configure ["Allow Less Secure Apps"](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in your Gmail account unless you are using 2FA in which case you would have to create an [Application Specific](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) password. You also may need to unlock your account with ["Allow access to your Google account"](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) to use SMTP.

Comment: I will try to create an application password for my Google account... 

@laggingreflex I tried to  "Allow Less Secure Apps" and it works for my local dev but it didn't work online...

Comment: @saljuama How do you create an application password in Google I don't find this page ? I have to create a pro account ?

Comment: [App passwords page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), it will redirect to your account, and i think you must enable 2-step verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @saljuama said you have to enable 2-step verification. And after create an application password.